# What are the best practices regarding paths?

Tags: path, pseudocode

I've been confused by this topic several times and been bitten by it. I've looked up many best practices articles and definitions but it seems to me that paths aren't exactly defined and what is an absolute and relative path seems to vary a lot depending on the context.

**Short version of the question: Always carry around (and convert into) Absolute Paths in code? But always write them out as relative.**

As a hobbyist I switch context constantly due to working on backend and frontend at the same time and I haven't come up with rules to be consistent and create portable code if paths are involved.

Essentially there seem to be to types of paths. **Absolute Path** and **Relative Path**. But I constantly come upon a third type which to me would probably be named **Absolute Relative Path**. The challenge for me is to know which one I should store and what complications could arise.

This is an Absolute Path:

```
/home/me/css/style.css
```

But not on Windows. What would the above do on Windows? It has to be this:

```
C:/home/me/css/style.css
```

What the Absolute Path that would work on Linux refers to using Windows is something completely different. It becomes relative to the current partition.

```
/home/me/css/style.css
```

becomes

```
C:/home/me/css/style.css
```

This is correct in this case, but might not be if the actual application is running on a different partition. Using Absolute Paths "Unix style" is therefore problematic if portability is required.

This is an Absolute Path to a directory:

```
/home/me/css/
```

But this is also an Absolute Path to a directory:

```
/home/me/css
```

Adding another slash is therefore purely conveying additional information to the writer, is it?

This is a Relative Path:

```
css/style.css
```

And to a directory:

```
css/
```

This is an Absolute Relative Path if used in an HTML document:

```
<a href="/css/style.css">Link</a>
```

While it refers to topmost css directory irregardless of where the address is currently pointing to, it still refers to the directory the webserver is handing out. As such it is absolute in use, but relative regarding the actual filesystem. Or in many cases, to the current working directory. The same is true for pure Relative Paths. If I create such paths I therefore have to keep in mind that even though they look like Absolute Paths, they are in fact not. Confusing.

If the application itself is moved to a different directory I therefore have to come up with a solution. And this is where I wonder if it is a bad idea to ever store Relative Paths. Say we write a static blog generator called blogger which is downloaded via git to some directory.

```
/home/me/blogger
```

All paths in the application are relative, we therefore call something akin to `create_dir('output')` in pseudocode. Now we might think it is a good idea to move the application to somewhere else and give the user the chance to supply the output directory himself. Suddenly all path definitions will break. They become `create_dir(absolute($output_dir) + 'output')`.

I find this kind of calculation to become very long and complicated at some point. Especially if there are still some files or directories which stay relative to the application, like templates or similar. But they might also move in the future so I find myself writing code like `copy_dir(cwd() + 'templates', absolute($output_dir) + 'output')`.

But wait, the current working dir is not necessarily the place where the application resides, especially on unix-like systems.
And how does absolute generate an absolute path if the application doesn't know whether it's absolute to the application directory or absolute to the current directory? We must assume the latter, so calling `absolute()` is not a good idea, rather `cwd() + $output_dir`. Thankfully `cwd()` usually returns an already absolute path. We can only do this if the path the user provided is actually relative, but not if it's absolute. Thankfully standard libraries have ways to deal with that, but the naive approach would blow up and we would end up with something like "C:/C:/css".

Assuming the user never provides absolute paths we could use:

`copy_dir(absolute(app_dir()) + 'output', cwd() + $output_dir)`

Then I say to myself, well, I have to do this everytime I work with those files, so why not do it once and carry around `$abs_output_dir` instead? Suddenly I come across the problem that I have to output an Absolute Relative Path into an HTML document and I can't use `$abs_output_dir` because I then somehow have to cut out the Absolute Part so it is relative to the user supplied `$output_dir`. At this point my mind usually brakes down and I either hardcode every path, or I carry around `$output_dir` `$abs_output_dir` and `$rel_abs_output_dir` as well as `$abs_app_dir` and try to keep all up to date.

As such the idea to only carry around Absolute Paths seems to be a good one, unless we every come to the point where we have to output Relative Paths or Absolute Relative Paths to a file. Is that how programmers usually do it?

Comment: Please tag your questions with the programming language you are using, or at least mention which programming language you are using.

Comment: The code is supposed to be pseudocode to illustrate my point. My problem is not confined to one programming language.

Comment: Psuedocode tends to be problematic on a site like StackOverflow because people who have used a different programming language may not be familiar with the notation used (such as dollar signs). It is more appropriate in a classroom setting where everyone understands the notation.

Comment: I always store and manipulate relative paths whenever possible. Storing absolute paths makes it hard to move applications around.

Comment: Just use relative paths. Saves a lot of hassle in my experience.